# C++: Unwanted Conversions between ostream and ofstream

Tags: c++, file, stream, persistence, overloading

I've been working on a personal dictionary application which can help you remembering words you learnt. It is operated via the CLI (just don't question this, it's kinda just a test and I got a weird passion for CLI apps). So, of course I am using `ostream`s for writing information on the CLI. I am used to write `operator<<` overloads (for `ostream`s) for every class so that I can build up a multi-level output system (basically every object can "speak" for itself).

In order to persist a dictionary object, I wanted to use `ofstream` and write a file with it. Naturally, I wrote `operator<<` overloads also for `ofstream` and in the same "layered" structure.

As a result, I have now two `operator<<` overloads in every class, like in "`Dictionary`":

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Dictionary&);
ofstream& operator<<(ofstream&, const Dictionary&);
```

(this is just the declaration in the header file)

Notice that it is **very important that these both overloads do *different* things.** I don't want to have some weird persistence-oriented special-format text on the CLI and also not user-friendly plain text in my file.

The problem is that, because of the inheritance structure of `ostream` and `ofstream`, **`ofstream` is sometimes implicitely converted to `ostream`**. And when this happens in the middle of my stack full of *file* output operations, the program suddenly jumps into the wrong overload and prints plain text in the file.

My question is simply: Is there a way to avoid or revert these unwanted implicit conversions in order to let my program jump into the right overloads? Or is there any other good way to fix this problem?

**EDIT 1**:

Someone pointed out in the comments that this is not an implicit converison. `ofstream` is sometimes "seen" as its base class `ostream`. The problem is that at some point the object "forgets" that it is an `ofstream` and loses all file-related information. From there on it is only an `ostream` and that's what I meant with the "conversion".

**EDIT 2:**

The exact point in the program where the "unwanted conversion" happens can be found here:

```
ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& of, const Section& s) {
    return s.print_ofstream(of);
}
```

So this operator overoad calls "`print_ofstream`":

```
ofstream& Section::print_ofstream(ofstream& of) const {
    of << "sec" << Util::ID_TO_STRING(section_id) << ":\n";
    for (pair<Wordlist, Wordlist> pwl : translations) {
        of << '{' << pwl.first << '=' << pwl.second << "}\n";
    }
    of << "#\n";
    return of;
}
```

Note that "pwl" is a pair of two `Wordlist`s, therefore pwl.first / pwl.second is a `Wordlist`. So, normally the line `of << '{' << pwl.first << '=' << pwl.second << "}\n";` should call the `ofstream` `operator<<` overload in `Wordlist`. But it doesn't. Instead, the other overload method is called:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Wordlist& wl) {
    return wl.print_ostream(o);
}
```

Comment: It isn't that `ofstream` is being implicitly converted, it's that `ostream` is the *base class* of `ofstream`.

Comment: That's true, but I am a little bit confused that a method of the return type ofstream can return ostream. I would understand it the other way round...

Comment: Can you show the problematic code?

Comment: @JETM yes of course. There is now an "EDIT 2" providing this information

Answer (score 0):

You have overloaded only the specific `operator<<` needed for streaming `Dictionary`, `Section`, `Wordlist`, etc objects to a `std::ofstream`, but `std::ofstream` *inherits* MANY other `operator<<`s from `std::ostream`, and those operators all take `ostream&` as input and return `ostream&` as output. So, for example, `of << "sec"` will return `ostream&` even though `of` is a `std::ofstream`, and then that `ostream&` is used for subsequent `<<` calls until `;` is reached.  Those are the "implicit conversions" you are experiencing.

The real question is, WHY do you want `operator<<` to output different data depending on the type of `std::ostream` being written to?  That goes against C++'s streaming model.  If you really want that, you would have to change `print_ofstream(ofstream&)` to `print_ostream(ostream&)` and then dynamically detect the actual `std::ostream` derived type using `dynamic_cast`.  Same with `Wordlist`, and any other classes that need it.

A simpler and safer option would be to just store a flag inside of your classes to control how their data should be output, regardless of the type of `std::ostream` being used.  Then you can set that flag as needed.  Maybe even define some helper I/O manipulators to set those flags while making `<<` calls.